# Write to session on anchor click ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have ASP.NET based site. For example I have two anchors:

```
<a id="sortByPopular" runat="server" href="url1">Popular</a>
<a id="sortByRecent" runat="server" href="url2">Recent</a>
```

At code behind I can build href attributes:

```
sortByPopular.Href = BuildURL(POPULAR);
sortByRecent.Href = BuildURL(RECENT);
```

And I want to remember, which sort order user is using on listing page. I think there should be the way to create new Session variable when user clicks on link. Could someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LinkButton

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="sortByRecent" Text="Recent" OnClick="sortByRecent_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

codebehind

```
protected void sortByRecent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //do your session thing here
}
```